# Change default font for math environments

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts

In beamer, is there way to have mathematical expressions put in serif by default, while the rest of the text is in sans-serif?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}  
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Here goes the text $x + y  = Z$
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]